# 13.4 and sony t2xp no launcher etc

Tags: launcher

I have a sony t2xp laptop with xp installed. I have installed 32bit ubuntu 13.4 as a dual boot but I have no launcher or toolbar.

I have tried going through ccsm and re enabling unity but it never stays enabled and it doesn't start the launcher.

I realise this is an old laptop will it support this version of ubuntu ?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You don't have enough RAM memory. Your laptop has 512MB RAM according to Google, and Ubuntu 13.04 needs at least 768MB. Also your CPU is rather small. I recommend that you consider Xubuntu which needs only 512MB RAM and also Xubuntu version 12.04 LTS instead of 13.04 so you won't have to install another Ubuntu release or upgrade the OS until April, 2015.